# Multiline problem of UILabel embed in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Here is the screenshot of UIView with its constraints.

It is located in a tableview cell

[image]

When I use UIlabel without UIView I can get it to grow multiline. But It doesn't work with UIView which I use for padding

[image]

I tried sth like

```
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.label.sizeToFit()
        cell.label.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.view.sizeToFit()
```

How can I make multiline work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure you did not set any required static height for the **label** nor the **view** itself.
- Make the **label** (which is the subview of the **view**) edges equal to the superview's.
- Last but not least, set the values of content hugging and content compression resistance priorities to those you need.

And btw. - If all you need is the grey background that visually wraps the label by some constant, the label doesn't have to be a subview of that grey background view, just set the view's edges to the label's ones and do some layout corrections to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**1**.Set **background color** from attribute inspector for Label.Don't use background view for label.

**2**.Set UIlabel's **lines** property to no of lines that you want.

**3**.Don't give height constraints.give only top leading trailing and width.

Answer (score 0):

1- Set UIlabel's lines property to no of lines that you want, you can set it to 0, then the UILabel will automatically resize

2- Don't give height constraints, give only top leading trailing and width

3-return in heightForRowAtIndexPath: UITableView.automaticDimension (Swift 4.2)